# AKKA : How to provide maximum number of retries with BackoffSupervisor?

Tags: akka

I want to use `BackoffSupervisor` using **AKKA**, with maximum number of retry feature.

I tried using following approaches, however, child actor still runs continuously on stop or on failure:

```
//approach 1
final Props supervisorProps = BackoffSupervisor.props(
  Backoff.onStop(
    childActor.props(),
    "childrActor",
    Duration.ofSeconds(3),
    Duration.ofSeconds(12),
    0.2)
);   


//approach 2
final Props supervisorProps = BackoffSupervisor.props(
  Backoff.onStop(
    childActor.props(),
      "childrActor",
      Duration.ofSeconds(3),
      Duration.ofSeconds(12),
      0.2)
  .withSupervisorStrategy(
    OneForOneStrategy.apply(
      3,
      Duration.create(12, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
      true,
      DeciderBuilder
        .match(Exception.class, e -> SupervisorStrategy.restart())
        .build()))
  );
```

Comment: @Tatranskymedved updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolved this issue by using Backoff.onFailure instead of Backoff.onStop for approach2.